# Django : How to filter in between 2 same objects in 2 different models?

Tags: python, django, ms-access, django-models, microsoft-graph-api

**Please also read my NOTE at the end of my question.**

**Question**: I have integrated Microsoft Graph API with my django project and after login in successfully, I am storing both access and refresh token in 2 different models. the models are `ModelA` and `ModelB`.

Assume that microsoft organisation account holders get their access and refresh token saved in `ModelA`.
The `ModelA` includes the following attributes:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(null = True , blank = True)
    for_user = models.ForeignKey(ModelX, null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_firm = models.ForeignKey(ModelMain, 
    related_name="microsoft_for_firm", null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    access_token = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    refresh_token = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and microsoft personal accounts holders get their access and refresh tokens saved in `ModelB`.
The `ModelB` includes the following attributes:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(null = True , blank = True)
    for_user = models.ForeignKey(ModelX, null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_firm = models.ForeignKey(ModelMain, 
    related_name="microsoft_for_personal", null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    access_token = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    refresh_token = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**What I want to Achieve?**

I want to open a docx file using either microsoft organisation or personal account. before opening the file, I want to let the user open the file according to their account type. If a account type is personal, then it should use `ModelB`'s `access_token` or `refresh_token`.

If an account type is organisation then it should use the `ModelA`'s `access_token` or `refresh_token`.

This is what I am doing right now. according to my current logic, it always calls ModelA despite of getting user type.

```
`refresh_token = None
access_token = None
userprofile = None
try:

    profile = ModelF.objects.get(
        user=request.user, account_type='Attorney')
    userprofile = ModelMain.objects.get(attorneyprofile=profile)

except:

    userprofile = ModelX.objects.get(
        user=request.user, account_type='AttorneyStaff')
    userprofile = userprofile.created_by
org_refresh_token = ModelA.objects.filter(for_firm=userprofile, refresh_token__startswith='0.AU').first()
if org_refresh_token:
    access_token = org_refresh_token.access_token
    print("\n Access Token :", access_token)
    user_type = get_user_type(access_token)
    print("\n User type in get refresh token :", user_type)
    if user_type == 'Member' and org_refresh_token.refresh_token.startswith("0.AU"):
        print("\n Member found \n")
        refresh_token = org_refresh_token.refresh_token
        print("\n REFRESH TOKEN Organisation :", refresh_token)
    else:
        per_refresh_token = ModelB.objects.filter(for_firm=userprofile, refresh_token__startswith='M.R3').first()
        if per_refresh_token:
            refresh_token = per_refresh_token.refresh_token
            print("\n REFRESH TOKEN Personal:", refresh_token)
else:
    per_refresh_token = ModelB.objects.filter(for_firm=userprofile, refresh_token__startswith='M.R3').first()
    refresh_token = per_refresh_token.refresh_token
    print("\n REFRESH TOKEN Organisation:", refresh_token)
```

`
NOTE: It works fine when there is no data in either model. but it always calls the model that I call first when there is access and refresh token in both models at the same time.

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: What have you done to debug this issue?

Comment: I am doing different logic but failed. I applied out of box solutions as well but still facing issues.

Comment: Debug: step through code, watch variables - are variables set as expected? As written, org_refresh_token and per_refresh_token must be either true or false.

Comment: org_refresh_token and per_refresh_token have refrsh_tokens respectively.

Comment: and there is nothing wrong with any varibale. everything is fine.